# How to add dates to database records for trending analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL server database table that contain a few thousand records. These records are populated by PowerShell scripts on a weekly basis. These scripts basically overwrite last weeks data so the table only has information pertaining to the previous week. I would like to be able to take a copy of that tables data each week and add a date column with that day's date beside each record. I  need this so can can do trend analysis in the future.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the PowerShell scripts to edit them. Is there any way I can accomplish this using MS SQL server or some other way?

Comment: Sure add a nullable datetime column to the table. Then when you want to update the date with new values you simply update the table. Update MyTable Set MyDate = @MyDate where MyDate IS NULL Something like that.

Comment: I will try that. The table in question is used by other people so do you know a way I can clone a table in SQL server and then I can add the column to the cloned table?

Comment: Why do you need to clone it? Unless the queries are using select * or the inserts don't specify the columns there should be no impact to anything else.

Comment: I think he needs the new table because the original gets overwritten each week so he can't see historical data.

Comment: I only have read access on that particular table. So I would need to take the data on a weekly basis, add a date value and then insert it into a table I have created that I have write permission to. I can then use this table for trending analysis in the future. I'm just not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following. Create a table that will contain the clone + dates. Insert the results from your original table along with the date into your clone table. From your description you don't need a where clause because the results of the original table are wiped out only holding new data. After the initial table creation there is no need to do it again. You'll just simply do the `insert` piece. Obviously the below is very basic and is just to provide you the framework.

```
CREATE TABLE yourTableClone
(
  col1 int
  col2 varchar(5)...
  col5 date
)


insert into yourTableClone
select *, getdate()
from yourOriginalTable
```

Comment: Yes that's correct I wouldn't need a where clause. Is there any way I can get this query to run on a scheduled job? That way I get new data  for each week. I know I could write a PowerShell script and put it on Task Scheduler but I'm interested to know if I can do this from within SQL Server.

Comment: @LiamF.O'Neill Yes. Create the table first. Then go and create a job under SQL Server Agent. Give the job a name, go to steps and create a new step to execute t-sql. The part you'll be executing is only the insert or a call to a stored procedure that handles the insert. Then go to schedules and schedule it. There are a bunch of options in jobs so I can't go over them all but the answer is yes you can create and schedule a job to execute sql unless you are using SQL Express.